# Url Rewrite for hosted application on IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core, iis-express, asp.net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.1

I have developed asp.net mvc core 3.0 web application and deployed in windows server. I would like to hide controller name in url.

Example :

**orginal url**  : www.example.com/test/authenticate/login

**expected url** : www.example.com/test/login

Im not sure about it by achieve it code or IIS.

startup.cs route code.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
       endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
           name: "default",
           pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

});
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Attribute routing:

```
[Route("/")]
public class AuthenticateController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("login")]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok("Ok");
    }
}
```

Comment: It is working if im not add Route on controller. Could you please explain about [Route("/")]?

Comment: The AuthenticateController.Get() action will be executed for  the URL paths(root+Action route) /login